# buscar con Jquery una cadena especifica en el atributo "src" de la imagen

Tags: jquery, nodejs, scraping

Estoy intentando buscar una cadena con Jquery en el link de una imagen "src", yo he conseguido sacar los titulos, precios y url pero con la imagen no lo consiguo porque existe en el codigo HTML un codigo similar que si consigo sacar la url de la imagen  y para evitar esto lo busco con el contenido de una cadena en la url de la imagen,  he intentado estas dos opciones y obtengo undefined:

```
image: $item.find( ".lazy:[src*='images.***.com']").attr('src'),
image: $item.find( ".lazy:contains('images.***.com')").attr('src'),
```

este el codigo HTML

```
   <div class="thumbnail_container">

                          <a title="grupajes motos,muebles,cajas,enseres,por españ... " href="//www.****.com/madrid/grupajes-motosmueblescajasenserespor-espan/a130091052/?ca=28_s&amp;st=a&amp;c=71" target="_self">
                                  <img class="lazy" src="//images.****.com/c_238x178/292/29258279911.jpg" alt="grupajes motos,muebles,cajas,enseres,por españ... " title="grupajes motos,muebles,cajas,enseres,por españ... " border="0" style="display: inline;">
                          </a>

                      </div>
```

y este el codigo similar en donde siempre sale lo mismo en la src

```
                  <a title="piano digital Roland HP-2e " href="//www.***.com/madrid/piano-digital-roland-hp-2e/a134720636/?ca=28_s&amp;st=a&amp;c=37" target="_self">
                          <img class="lazy" src="//www.****.com/img/1x1.gif" alt="piano digital Roland HP-2e " title="//images.****.com/c_238x178/511/51104521867.jpg" border="0">
                  </a>

              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El [selector de atributo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo) se utiliza **sin los dos puntos** (`:`)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let $item = $('.thumbnail_container');
let image = $item.find( '.lazy[src*="images.vibbo.com"]').attr('src');
console.log(image);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail_container">

  <a title="grupajes motos,muebles,cajas,enseres,por españ... " href="//www.vibbo.com/madrid/grupajes-motosmueblescajasenserespor-espan/a130091052/?ca=28_s&amp;st=a&amp;c=71" target="_self">
  
    <img class="lazy" src="//www.vibbo.com/img/1x1.gif" border="0" style="display: inline;">
    
    <img class="lazy" src="//images.vibbo.com/c_238x178/292/29258279911.jpg" alt="grupajes motos,muebles,cajas,enseres,por españ... " title="grupajes motos,muebles,cajas,enseres,por españ... " border="0" style="display: inline;">
    
    <img class="lazy" src="//www.vibbo.com/img/1x1.gif" border="0" style="display: inline;">
    
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Ok funciona , gracias!!